# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable (Caused by org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)

Tags: scala, hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I want to write transformed stream to Elasticsearch index as follows:

```
transformed.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
    val messages = rdd.map(prepare)
    messages.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("-", classOf[NullWritable], classOf[MapWritable], classOf[EsOutputFormat], ec)
  }
})
```

The line `val messages = rdd.map(prepare)` throws an error (see below). I get stuck with it trying different ways to solve this issue (e.g. adding `@transient` next to `val conf`), but nothing seems to work.

> 6/06/28 19:23:00 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job
>   1467134580000 ms.0 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not
>   serializable  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)   at
>   de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1.apply(EsStream.scala:77)
>     at
>   de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1.apply(EsStream.scala:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
>   Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, value: Configuration:
>   core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml,
>   yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml)
>     - field (class: de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream, name: de$kp$spark$elastic$stream$EsStream$$conf, type: class
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
>     - object (class de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream, de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream@6b156e9a)
>     - field (class: de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1, name: $outer, type: class de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream)
>     - object (class de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1, )
>     - field (class: de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$2, name:
>   $outer, type: class
>   de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1)
>     - object (class de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$2,
>   )  at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
>     ... 30 more Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)   at
>   de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1.apply(EsStream.scala:77)
>     at
>   de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1.apply(EsStream.scala:75)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)    at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
>     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)   at
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
>   Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, value: Configuration:
>   core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml,
>   yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml)
>     - field (class: de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream, name: de$kp$spark$elastic$stream$EsStream$$conf, type: class
>   org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration)
>     - object (class de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream, de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream@6b156e9a)
>     - field (class: de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1, name: $outer, type: class de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream)
>     - object (class de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1, )
>     - field (class: de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$2, name:
>   $outer, type: class
>   de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1)
>     - object (class de.kp.spark.elastic.stream.EsStream$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$2,
>   )  at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
>     ... 30 more

Is it somehow related to the configuration of Hadoop? (I refer to this message: `class: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, value: Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml`)

**UPDATE:**

```
class EsStream(name:String,conf:HConf) extends SparkBase with Serializable {

  /* Elasticsearch configuration */ 
  val ec = getEsConf(conf)               

  /* Kafka configuration */
  val (kc,topics) = getKafkaConf(conf)

  def run() {

    val ssc = createSSCLocal(name,conf)

    /*
     * The KafkaInputDStream returns a Tuple where only the second component
     * holds the respective message; we therefore reduce to a DStream[String]
     */
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createStream[String,String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder](ssc,kc,topics,StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK).map(_._2)
    /*
     * Inline transformation of the incoming stream by any function that maps 
     * a DStream[String] onto a DStream[String]
     */
    val transformed = transform(stream)
    /*
     * Write transformed stream to Elasticsearch index
     */
    transformed.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        val messages = rdd.map(prepare)
        messages.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("-", classOf[NullWritable], classOf[MapWritable], classOf[EsOutputFormat], ec)
      }
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()    

  }

  def transform(stream:DStream[String]) = stream

  private def getEsConf(config:HConf):HConf = {

    val _conf = new HConf()

    _conf.set("es.nodes", conf.get("es.nodes"))
    _conf.set("es.port", conf.get("es.port"))

    _conf.set("es.resource", conf.get("es.resource"))

    _conf

  }

  private def getKafkaConf(config:HConf):(Map[String,String],Map[String,Int]) = {

    val cfg = Map(
      "group.id" -> conf.get("kafka.group"),

      "zookeeper.connect" -> conf.get("kafka.zklist"),
      "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> conf.get("kafka.timeout")

    )

    val topics = conf.get("kafka.topics").split(",").map((_,conf.get("kafka.threads").toInt)).toMap   

    (cfg,topics)

  }

  private def prepare(message:String):(Object,Object) = {

    val m = JSON.parseFull(message) match {
      case Some(map) => map.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
      case None => Map.empty[String,String]
    }

    val kw = NullWritable.get

    val vw = new MapWritable
    for ((k, v) <- m) vw.put(new Text(k), new Text(v))

    (kw, vw)

  }

}
```

Comment: The object of org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration class seems to be globally declared as a field. Try to make it local.

Comment: @amit_kumar: Thanks. Iǘe just posted the complete class. COuld you please indicate where should I make org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration local?

Comment: What is HConf? That is causing problem. Check if that is serializable or not.

Comment: @amit_kumar: It comes from `org.apache.hadoop.conf.{Configuration => HBase}`, where `public class Configuration implements Iterable<Map.Entry<String,String>>,
                                      Writable {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `conf:HConf` from class constructor of `EsStream` and write it like `class EsStream(name:String)`.

Next create a method with signature : `public def init(conf:HConf):Map(String,String)`

In this method you will read desired configurations and update `ec` and `(kc,topics)` in this.

After this you should make a call to your run method.